# Is it possible to make Scala's JSON.parseFull() not to treat Integers as Decimals?

Tags: json, scala

I'm parsing this string using JSON.parseFull(). This method is really convenient to me because I need to get a Map

```
val jStr = """{"wt":"json","rows":500}"""
println( JSON.parseFull(jStr) )
```

here's the output:

```
Some(Map(wt -> json, rows -> 500.0)) // ´rows´ as Double
```

I'd like to get back an Integer instead of a Double.

```
Some(Map(wt -> json, rows -> 500)) // ´rows´ as Integer
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 8):

From [Scala's JSON documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3-RC2/scala/util/parsing/json/JSON$.html)

> The default conversion for numerics is into a double. If you wish to override this behavior at the global level, you can set the globalNumberParser property to your own (String => Any) function. If you only want to override at the per-thread level then you can set the perThreadNumberParser property to your function

in your case:

```
val myConversionFunc = {input : String => Integer.parseInt(input)}
JSON.globalNumberParser = myConversionFunc
```

scala> println( JSON.parseFull(jStr) )

Some(Map(wt -> json, rows -> 500))

Comment: How bad! That means I need to treat all the numbers as they were Integer or Decimal... For the case I posted as example is Ok, but what  if I had to deal with a mixed case of numbers? It would be great if I could get non fractional as Integers and fractional as Decimal. I guess I can't rely on JSON.parseFull() and I need to write some extra code in order to get what I want.

Comment: Not necessarily. If floating point numbers always have a dot, you could write a conversion function that returned a Float for "100.0" and an Int for "100"

Comment: Scala's JSON documentation link Not found.

Answer (score 6):

The default conversion of numerics is **Double** in **scala**

Basically you need to set the default number parser `globalNumberParser` to `int` first

```
JSON.globalNumberParser = {
  in =>
    try in.toInt catch { case _: NumberFormatException => in.toDouble}
}

val jStr = """{"wt":"json","rows":500}"""
println( JSON.parseFull(jStr) )
```

Output:

```
Some(Map(wt -> json, rows -> 500)) // ´rows´ as Integer
```

Comment: very nice solution