# Scala Map values getting printed as float and integer randomly

Tags: java, scala, dictionary

I am printing value of scala Map in Java class like below

```
Option<Object> data = JSON.parseFull((String)zkClient.readData(statePath));    
scala.collection.immutable.Map<String, Object> leaderInfo = scala.collection.immutable.Map<String, Object>) data.get();
    System.out.println(leaderInfo.toString();
```

But I am surprised that sometimes the value comes as floating point number

```
controller_epoch -> 6.0, leader -> 1.0, version -> 1.0, leader_epoch -> 4.0, isr -> List(1.0)
```

and sometimes as Integer.

```
controller_epoch -> 6, leader -> 1, version -> 1, leader_epoch -> 4, isr -> List(1)
```

I want the data to be always parsed as Integer. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I think this is a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945949/is-it-possible-to-make-scalas-json-parsefull-not-to-treat-integers-as-decimal  
Set JSON.globalNumberParser.

Comment: Got it .. couldn't find it in search before.