# How to parse JSON data in Scala?

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I am new to Scala. I want to parse JSON data in scala.

I want to loop this data and in each iteration extract data for `id,v,q`, and `t` from values

I am using below code to parse it to JSON

```
import scala.util.parsing.json._

val data =
  """
{
  "timestamp":
  1518501114949
  , "values":
  [
  {
    "id":
    "abc"
    , "v":
    0
    , "q":
    true
    , "t":
    1518501114487
  }
  ,
  {
    "id":
    "xyz"
    , "v":
    15
    , "q":
    true
    , "t":
    1518501114494
  }
  ]
}
"""

val parsed = JSON.parseFull(data)
```

I am getting output as below

```
 Some(Map(timestamp -> 1.518501114949E12, values -> List(Map(id -> abc, v -> 0.0, q -> true, t -> 1.518501114487E12), Map(id -> xyz, v -> 15.0, q -> true, t -> 1.518501114494E12), Map(id -> klm, v -> 12.6999998, q -> true, t -> 1.518501114487E12), Map(id -> 901.Hotmelt.PSA.0759_PSAM01_Vac, v -> 1.0, q -> true, t -> 1.518501114494E12))))
```

but I don't know how to loop and fetch all values after that

and I am not understanding why timestamp is getting converted to E12 values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Scala using standard Scala classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170949/how-to-parse-json-in-scala-using-standard-scala-classes)

Comment: The [ujson](https://github.com/lihaoyi/upickle) library is the modern, best solution for parsing JSON.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the parseFull returns an Option with an Any inside, so you first need to get rid of that:

With this code below, you will keep the values:

```
val listAsAny = parsed match {
  case Some(e:Map[Any,Any]) => e("values")
  case None => println("Failed.")
}
```

But they still as Any, so you can transform it as follows:

```
val values = listAsAny.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Any]]]
```

Now values is a List of maps with the following values, and you can get the values inside as you will do with a regular List

```
List(Map(id -> abc, v -> 0.0, q -> true, t -> 1.518501114487E12), Map(id -> xyz, v -> 15.0, q -> true, t -> 1.518501114494E12))
```

For instance, to retrieve the ids you can do:

```
values.map(_("id"))
```

And the result will be:

```
List(abc, xyz)
```

Comment: Is there any other method to parse data except json.parseFull()

Comment: and why timestamp is getting converted to E12

Comment: Because it consider it to be a number. Check this answer, it may help 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170949/how-to-parse-json-in-scala-using-standard-scala-classes

Comment: As a provisional solution, you can retrieve your timestamps as follows:


values.map(_("t").toString.replaceAll("\\.", "").replaceAll("E12", ""))

Comment: @SCouto no, for christ sake don't use string replace to manipulate numbers! Just cast it to long with `.toLong`. Anyway, this accepted answer didn't solve this problem, that `JSON.parseFull` function for some cryptic reason turns all numbers into `double`, which is silly in case of large integers, where one can easily loose precision

Answer (score 1):

The [upickle](https://github.com/lihaoyi/upickle) library allows for a robust, elegant solution.

```scala
val parsed = ujson.read(data)
parsed("values").arr.map(_("id").str) // ArrayBuffer("abc", "xyz")
```

See [here](https://mungingdata.com/scala/read-write-json/) for a more detailed discussion on why upickle / ujson is the best Scala library for parsing JSON.

Comment: Is there any way that it could be used for checking the schema and datatypes?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question

> and I am not understanding why timestamp is getting converted to E12 values

this particular JSON parser treats all numbers as `Double` fractions, so that's why you get scientific notation with fraction × 10¹² (`E12` suffix). There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949016/2369637) on how to change this parser's default behaviour for numbers, namely one can implement own parser which would return `Long` instead of the default `Double`.

It makes more sense if you have large integer timestamps to parse, because you could easily start loosing precision (timestamps would be rounded if exceeded 2^51 ~= 4,5×10¹⁵, which is border of `Double` type fractional part precision). However, in your case numbers like 1518501114949 are 100 times smaller, so there's still some safe margin and probably casting the resulting `Double` to `Long` with `.toLong` method should be enough.